# the meaning of 出張ってくる？

Tags: translation

- ３年が出張って来たらマサルの名前出せばいいもんな
- If any3-year tries to mess with us, we just need to Name-Drop Masaru-kun.

Is this right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

出張る used like this is not simple "to come/go", but often has a connotation of "unnecessarily" or "although unwanted". It implies a 3年 is unwelcome, so you may translate this like "to bother to jump in", "to interfere" or "to butt in". Translating it as "to try to mess" may be too strong, though.

Answer (score 2):

It is [出張{でば}る](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E5%87%BA%E5%BC%B5%E3%82%8B/#jn-152268). The particular meaning here is

> ２ 仕事などをするために、**ある所に出向く。**出張する。

A translation for the sentence would be *to step in*.